# How to handle nested objects multipart/form-data for swagger( openapi: "3.0.0")

Tags: express, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, jsdoc

I am creating an express api and documenting it using swagger jsdoc
my model looks like this

Property Model :

```
{
name : "string",
address : {
street : "string",
pincode : "string"
}
photos : files
}
```

I have created an post endpoint and I want to interactively test it using swagger

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /properties:
 *  post:
 *      tags : [Properties]
 *      summary : create property
 *      security:
 *          - jwt: []
 *      requestBody:
 *          content:
 *              multipart/form-data:
 *                  schema:
 *                      type : object
 *                      properties :
 *                        name :
 *                          type : string
 *                        photos :
 *                          type : array
 *                          items :
 *                            type : string
 *                            format : binary
 *                        address :
 *                          type : object
 *                          properties :
 *                            street :
 *                              type : string
 *                            city :
 *                              type : string
 *
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description : array of all properties
 *          500:
 *              description : error with reason
 */
router.post("/", authenticate, create_property);
```

when I set request body content to `multipart/form-data`
I am not able to read `address.street`

however when I set request body content to `application/json` I can read `address.street`

Edit:
added controller code

```
exports.create_property = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.address.street);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return sendErrorResponse(res, "error creating property", error, 500);
  }
};
```

I am just console logging values I receive, for address when I set request body as multipart form-data I get address as string but `req.files` has proper files in it

```
address: '{\r\n' +
    '  "street": "string",\r\n' +
    '  "landmark": "string",\r\n' +
    '  "pincode": "string"\r\n' +
    '}'
```

but when request body is set to application/json I get a proper object, however `req.files` is `undefined`

```
 address: { street: 'string', landmark: 'string', pincode: 'string' }
```

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: @Helen I have added controller code and some more explanation